# Spring Reactor: What's the corresponding class to Optional<T>?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

So I have a `Flux<Foo>` and I want to map each `Foo` to `Baz`. The thing is, `getBaz(Foo foo)` may throw an `IOException`.

So I thought about having `Mono<Baz> getBazRx(Foo foo)` method which will return either a `Mono.just(baz)` or `Mono.empty()` in case of an exception.

Then will end up with `Flux<Mono<Baz>>` which kind of reminds the `Optional<T>` container.

Is that the way doing that in Spring Reactor? How to consume it properly?

Comment: do you want to skip the element producing an error in `getBaz(Foo foo)` or terminate the flux?

Comment: I think Mono<T> is the equivalent of Optional<T>, if we consider that they are both Monads.

Comment: @Sindbad90, I'd like to treat it differently (i.e. write to log). But would love to hear from you about the other scenario as well actually!

Comment: how you want to handle the error depends on your need, I've written an answer assuming you wish to log and continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reactive streams, "optionals" are generally handled by removing absent elements from the stream (e.g. an empty `Mono`, or a `Flux` with the element dropped.), rather than having a `Flux<Optional>`, `Mono<Optional>`, or `Flux<Mono>`

When calling a synchronous `getBaz` method, you can use a single `.handle` operation, like this:

```java
flux
    .handle((foo, sink) -> {
        try {
            // propagate Baz down the stream
            sink.next(getBaz(foo));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Since sink.next is not called here,
            // the problematic element will be dropped from the stream
            log.error(e);
        }
    })
```

When calling an asynchronous `getBazRx` method (returning `Mono`), you can use `onErrorResume` inside a `flatMap`/`flatMapSequential`/`concatMap`, like this:

```java
flux
    .flatMap(foo -> getBazRx(foo)
        .onErrorResume(t -> {
            log.error(t);
            return Mono.empty();
        }))
```

(Or you could move `.onErrorResume` inside `.getBazRx`, depending on where you want to catch and ignore the exception)

Also, since you alluded to it in your question... if you were to create `getBazRx` that wraps `getBaz`, you should *never* do something like this if `getBaz` has the potential to block:

```java
Mono<Baz> getBazRx(Foo foo) {
    // BAD!!!
    try {
        return Mono.just(getBaz(foo));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Mono.error(e)  // or Mono.empty() if you want to ignore
    }
}
```

That implementation is really just a synchronous method *impersonating* an async method.  There are two problems with it:

1. Work is done immediately, instead of after subscribing to the returned `Mono`
2. If `getBaz` blocks, you could end up blocking the event loop

Instead, you should defer work until the mono is subscribed, and run any blocking operation on a `Scheduler` intended for blocking operations, like this:

```java
Mono<Baz> getBazRx(Foo foo) {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
            try {
                return getBaz(foo);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw Exceptions.propagate(e);  // or return null to ignore and complete empty
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());  // run on a scheduler suitable for blocking work
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually `getBaz` is a blocking method, so these insights really helped!

Comment: No problem.  If `getBaz` is blocking, then you'll need to either wrap it like I have shown in getBazRx, or make sure the `.handle` operation runs in a scheduler suitable for blocking work (e.g. `Schedulers.elastic()`)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to skip the error (just log it for instance), you can use `onErrorContinue`. Also, since `getBaz` throws a checked exception, we need to catch it and `return` (not throw) a `RuntimeException` instead. Reactor has a utility method to do this `Exceptions.propagate`:

```java
flux
  .map(foo -> {
      try {
        return getBaz(foo);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return Exceptions.propagate(e);
      }
  })
  .onErrorContinue(RuntimeException.class, (t, b) -> log.error(t))
  .subscribe(baz -> log.info("Read value {}", baz));
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I need!

Comment: Actually no, I'm getting `unhandledException` (if you don't mind, I'll reopen the question) on `getBaz` as it is throwing a checked exception.

Comment: that's my bad, I'll try to update the answer; handling checked exceptions in within an operation in reactor isn't as straightforward.

Comment: I have updated the answer, let me know if this fixes your problems.

Comment: `onErrorContinue` is quite an advanced operator and shouldn't be advocated that liberally... it is a departure from the Reactive Streams standard behavior and is only supported by a subset of operators. Plus contrary to other error-recovery operators it influences ALL operators upwards of it in the chain. So use with caution.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Fortunately, OP got a better answer.